# How to get rid of extra space selection when selecting text in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I select a block of text in VSCode, it automatically selects an extra space at the beginning and end of the selection, as well as any linebreaks in the middle. This can be seen in the picture below as indicated. How do I get rid of this extra selection?

[image]

Comment: How are you making these block selections?

Comment: it's just selected as usual -- drag with the cursor.

Comment: If I had to guess, it's probably selecting the "invisible" newline characters. In a sense this is nice, because you may or may not want to select the newline character when selecting text in a code editor.

Comment: it's mostly undesirable at the beginning and end because I can't tell whether or not I have selected the space between "subsets" and "in", for example. In the picture, I started the selection at "in", but it looks like I selected the space as well.

Answer (score 0):

What Visual Studio Code is selecting are the invisible newline characters.

Newline characters are invisible characters that specify a new line.

---

To disable this, you can install an extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace. This extension is called [Remove Final Newlines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DoCode.vscode-remove-final-newlines).

To install and enable it, you can follow the steps below.

1. In Visual Studio Code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, and search for *Remove Final Newlines*.
2. Select the extension with the author *DoCode*. Then, install it by clicking the Install button.
3. To format your code when saved, open `settings.json`, then add the following key and value.

   ```json
   {
     "files.removeFinalNewLine": true
   }
   ```
4. If you don't want it to be automatic, you can edit `keybindings.json`, and add the following.

   ```json
   {
     "command": "removeFinalNewlines.formatAndRemoveFinalNewlines",
     "key": "alt+f",
     "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
   }
   ```

   This will only format your document when the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is clicked (or a custom one; just specify it in `keybindings.json`).

---

In summary, to remove newlines, you need to install the [Remove Final Newlines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DoCode.vscode-remove-final-newlines) extension in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but sadly it doesn't do anything to fix the problem.